# Set selected value of typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using the [twitter bootstrap typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead).

I have customized the typehead so I can select a pair **value/label**

```
$.each(data.medicines,function(index,values){

    _med=new Object()
    _med.value=values.LYF
    _med.id=values.LYF_NUMER
    _medicines.push(_med)

})

//Fill typeahead with data
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    // note that "value" is the default setting for the property option
    source:_medicines,
    onselect: function(obj) { showdetails(obj) }
})
```

How can I set the selected value using Javascript ?

```
For exemple $("#mytypehead").val(43);
```

Comment: Why is this with a -1 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [the `typeahead.js` documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#jquerytypeaheadsetquery-query) (which is much more detailed than [the `bootstrap-typeahead.js` docs in Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead)):

> ### jQuery#typeahead('setQuery', query)
>
> Sets the current query of the typeahead. This is always preferable to using `$("input.typeahead").val(query)`, which will result in unexpected behavior. To clear the query, simply set it to an empty string.

### 2016 Update (setQuery does not exist anymore) :

> jQuery#typeahead('val', val)
>   Sets the value of the typeahead. 
>   This should be used in place of jQuery#val.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('val', myVal);
```

[New documentation here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

Comment: @gpasse indeed. See my edit.

Comment: helpfully they've changed this to be `jQuery#typeahead('val', query)`