# Missing Source error when clearing Typeahead.JS query

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to use Twitter's typeahead.js on a field `("#addtags")` to suggest tags to add, but when I select something the field keeps the value I just entered when it should be cleared.

I've tried the solution provided here ([Set selected value of typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278709/set-selected-value-of-typeahead)) which is to use `$("#id").typeahead('setQuery', query);` to clear the field. However, when I do that I get an error in my console: `Uncaught Error: missing source.`

Is there a way around this? The code to clear the field is a line above the bottom, rest provided for context.

```
//===========================
//Typeahead.js
//===========================

var tagApi = $("#addtags").tagsManager();
var addtags = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d['tag']); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    dupChecker:true,
//  remote: '/tags/tags/search.json?q=%QUERY',
    prefetch: {url: '/tags/tags/search.json?q='}
});

addtags.initialize();

$('#addtags').typeahead({
    hint:true,
    highlight:true,
    autoselect:false,
    dupChecker:true,
    },
{
    displayKey: 'tag',
    source: addtags.ttAdapter(),
}).on('typeahead:selected', onTagSelect);

function onTagSelect($e, datum) {
    tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", datum['tag']);

    //This is where I'm trying to clear the input:
    $('#addtags').typeahead('setQuery', ''); 

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a jsfiddle to show how to clear the selected suggestion:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/ecq0c0ph/

Try searching for a movie and then select a suggestion; the suggestion will be used to populate some fields and then the query input control will be cleared.

In a nutshell, to clear the suggestion when it is selected, create an event handler for Typeahead's selected [event](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events), and then use its API to set the [value](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval-val) to an empty string e.g.

```
.bind("typeahead:selected", function () {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', '');
});
```